# Forwarding jsp from controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a boolean function in a java class.. the function returns true if executed else it has to be directed to a jsp page how do I do that.. I am not using any creation of objects nor req.getParameter().. I tried using `redirectView()`, its a function and getting errors.
Its something like..

```
boolean isValidate()
{

}

if(isValidate())
   return true;
else
```

Answer (score 2):

Try on your controller

Normal GET:

```
return "path/to/jsp";
```

Redirect:

```
return "redirect:/login";
```

When use redirect prefix, it will return to http://host/yourapp/login

Spring documentation for [redirect prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mvc.html#d0e10025)

For redirect example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoit() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller method returns a String, you can do:

```
return "redirect:/path/to/page";
```